# Rails form_for Error | How to Bind Nested ActiveRecord Object to Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I was developing a Ruby on Rails application. It has a nested route like so:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'trip_plans#index'
  resources :trip_plans do
    resources :places, except: [:show, :index]
  end
end
```

The `trip_plans` resource has a `TripPlan` model and the `places` resource has a `Place` model. According to the routes, the `new_trip_plan_place_path` is a route like `/trip_plans/:trip_plan_id/places/new`. The `views/places/new.html.haml` uses a `form_for` declaration to create a new place within the current `trip_plan`:

```
- content_for :title do
  %title Add a Place to Your Plan

%header.form-header
  .container.form-container
    .row
      .col-xs-12
        %h1 Add a Place
        %hr

%article
  %section
    .container.form-container
      = render 'form'
```

The corresponding `edit.html.haml` is essentially the same, calling the same `_form.html.haml` to render the form.

The `places_controller`'s both `new` and `edit` action is like:

```
def new
  @trip_plan = TripPlan.find(params[:trip_plan_id])
  @place = @trip_plan.places.build
end

def edit
  @trip_plan = TripPlan.find(params[:trip_plan_id])
  @place = @trip_plan.places.build
end
```

And the `_form.html.haml` uses the `@place` like so:

```
= form_for @place do |f|
```

But as `@place` is a dependent ActiveRecord object, Rails is not able to figure out the correct URLs for `new` and `edit` path. It always shows a new form even on `edit` page.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try changing this line `@place = @trip_plan.places.build` to `@place = Place.find(params[:id])` in `edit` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It always shows a new form even on edit page

I guess the problem is this line `@place = @trip_plan.places.build` in your `edit` method.

`@place = @trip_plan.places.build` is nothing but `@place = @trip_plan.places.new`, so ***Rails*** treats `@place` as a ***new instance*** even on ***edit form***.

Changing it to `@place = Place.find(params[:id])` should solve your problem.

***Update:***

You should also change the below

```
= form_for @place do |f|
```

to

```
= form_for [@trip_plan, @place] do |f|
```

Comment: Awesome Pavan, it works. But the edit form's `action` is still set to `new_trip_plan_place_path` e.g. `/trip_plans/1/place`.

Comment: @AbraarArique I didn't get it. What do you mean by action is still set to `new_trip_plan_place_path`. How are you going to edit form? through a link?

Comment: I mean that the new place form should submit it's data to `/trip_plans/:trip_plan_id/places` via POST and the edit form should submit to `/trip_plans/:trip_plan_id/places/:id` via PATCH/PUT request. But when I visit the form page (new or edit) it errors out that "undefined method `places_path`".

Comment: I think it's because by defining `@place = Place.find(params[:id])` Rails thinks `@place` as a full independent ActiveRecord object and thus trying to submit data via POST to `places_path` which it thinks something like `/places`. But in reality the route is nested through `trip_plans`, so every URL of `@place` is prefixed with `trip_plans/:trip_plan_id`.